# Как инициализировать вектор в структуре?

Tags: c++, vector

Хочу добавить в структуру переменную вектора. Проблема в том, что при обновлении вектора программа падает.

Можно ли инициализировать вектор в структуре без `push_back(2)` в main?

Comment: Покажите код, что вы хотите, и почему падает? так, заочно - ну что сказать?...

Comment: Есть к примеру структура `struct test {
vector <float> test_vector;
}`

И когда я пытаюсь обновлять вектор, то программа падает с ошибкой типа "Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 1.989 s". Потому что не инициализирован. Хочу попытаться обойтись без лишнего кода в main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе, можно так -

```
struct test
{
    vector <float> test_vector {2.0};
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    test t;
    cout << t.test_vector[0] << endl;
```

А можно и так:

```
    test q {{5.0}};
    cout << q.test_vector[0] << endl;
}
```

Но что-то у вас, видимо, не так в самой консерватории, раз программа вылетает на пустом векторе...

Comment: То что нужно, большое спасибо!